# Comparing two Arrays.map values dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs

I have two arrays first array `Deals` contains deal list where it has `dealId`, `buyerId`, `sellerId` and, the second array `Customer` contains customers list where it has `customerId`, `name`. I just want to compare `Deal.sellerId` to `Customer.customerId` and want to show the `Customer.name`.

Don't confuse with the `<DealDetail />` its a component which has attribute `sellerName`, for this component I want customer name value.

Deals Array:

`this.state.updatedDeals.map(deal => <DealDetail key={deal.id} dealID={deal.id} sellerName={deal.sellerId} buyerName={deal.buyerId} />)`

Customers Array:

`this.state.updatedCustomers.map(customer => <li key={customer.id} > {customer.name} </li>)>`

What I exactly wanting:

`<DealDetail sellerName={deal.sellerId===customer.customerId ? customer.name} : "Unknown" />)`

Comment: do `updatedDeals` and `updatedCustomers` have a one to one mapping always or they can have different lengths

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below.

```
this.state.updatedDeals.map(
    (deal) =>
    { 
        const c =   this.state.updatedCustomers.filter(customer=>deal.sellerId===customer.id);
        <DealDetail 
            key={deal.id} 
            dealID={deal.id}        
            sellerName={c.length ==1 ? c[0].name:'unknown'} 
            buyerName={deal.buyerId} 
        />
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let updatedDeals = [
  {dealId: 10, buyerId: 1, sellerId: 26},
  {dealId: 11, buyerId: 1, sellerId: 26},
  {dealId: 12, buyerId: 1, sellerId: 27},
];

let updatedCustomers = [
  {customerId: 26, customerName: 'Isaac'},
  {customerId: 28, customerName: 'Jane'}
];

let DealDisplay = [];

updatedCustomers.forEach(cust => {
  if(updatedDeals.some(deal => deal.sellerId === cust.customerId)){
    DealDisplay.push(cust);
  }
});
```

Why not separate the logic in order to promote maintainability and readability. You can extract the records into a separate array as temporary variable. Then render the view using the variable

Answer (score 0):

Fetched data from firestore:

```
updatedCustomers[doc.id] = doc.data();
```

And solved above problem with this:

```
this.state.updatedDeals.map(deal => (<DealDetail key={deal.id}

         sellerName={this.state.updatedCustomers[deal.sellerId].name}
         buyerName={this.state.updatedCustomers[deal.buyerId].name}

       />))
```